# how to use jstack to get stack trace history?

Tags: java

I use `"jdk1.6.0/bin/jstack -l PID > /tmp/stack-DATE.txt"` to get a current snapshot.

Is it possible to get a stack trace of a particular timestamp which is around 8 days old?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are attempting to get it from a dump that was captured at a previous point in time, then yes you can get it and it really doesn't matter how long back in time you wish to go.
If you are relying on a pid then the stack information will be current information.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't. Imagine how much memory/disk space it would consume to store all the snapshots. You can setup some job that dumps threads every second or so, but the JVM itself can only return the current stack state.